# Basic Javascript Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to setup a very basic jQuery image gallery.

You can see my attempts here: http://training.customstudio.co.uk/portfolio/detail/ee_project_four

I've duplicated the code from another site we created, have changed all the relevant div reference, but can't for the life of me get it working.

The images seem to be loading, but the jQuery effects not working.

Hopefully one of you guys can see the problem.

Thanks in advance,

Tom Perkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is beyond simple. 
Check in your head tag and find this..

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="-/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="-/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Correct them because they do not refer to actual javascript files but Html files

Comment: Sorry Neo, you've lost me. Why do you say they refer to HTML files?

Comment: Visit this site to download all files and learn how to use the slider
http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Comment: Neo, thanks for your help but the Nivo slider is working perfectly on the home page. My question relates this page (http://training.customstudio.co.uk/portfolio/detail/ee_project_four) and in particular, to the effect that should take place when changing the large image by clicking on the thumbnails. If you scroll to the bottom of the source code, you'll see the javascript that deals with that, but for some unknown reason, isn't working. Any ideas from anyone else is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but @neo is right: you're trying to load the scripts from http://training.customstudio.co.uk/portfolio/detail/ee_project_four/-/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js and they're not there. If the scripts work in the main page, you probably need `/-/js/...`

Comment: If you are having problems with folders use cdn such as http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using Expression Engine. The problem was caused by the JS link missing a '/' i.e. src="/-/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js". Thanks for eveyone's help!